# Which is MORE correct; Bob and Joe`s or Bob`s and Joe`s?

Tags: possessives

It says it all in the title.  Common is Bob and Joe's. But is it grammatically correct?

Comment: They mean slightly different things. "Bob and Joe's restaurant" is one restaurant, owned (or run) by both of them. "Bob's and Joe's restaurants" would be two restaurants, each owned by one of them.

Comment: But doesn't that beg the question that you are referring to two different entities; # 1 Bob and # 2 Joe's Restaurant?